# Styling UIDatePicker Programmatically

Tags: objective-c, colors, uidatepicker

I have a register form which contains age, when a user enters their age a UIDatePicker will pop up and they can select a date. I am running the following code in the `viewDidLoad` to achieve this:

```
- (void)configureAgePicker {

    //Initialise date picker
    UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    datePicker.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_UK"];

    //Add toolbar to keyboard
    UIToolbar *toolBar=[[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];
    UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(resignKeyboards)];
    UIBarButtonItem *space=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    [toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:space,doneBtn, nil]];

    //style popup
    toolBar.barTintColor = kPrimaryHighlightGradient;
    datePicker.backgroundColor = kPrimaryHighlight;
    datePicker.tintColor = kTextColor4;

    self.ageTextfield.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;
    self.ageTextfield.inputView = datePicker;

}
```

My problem is that I cannot change the colour properties of the date picker itself. I can set the colour of the toolbar (that works fine) but `datePicker.backgroundColor` & `datePicker.tintColor` don't appear to be doing anything. Here is an image of the textfield,

[image: Popup UIDatePicker]

I really want to change the colours of this popup to match the colour scheme of my app. I have styled `UIDatePickers` before through storyboards and remember having to use runtime variables to set the colour schemes (I couldn't through code). Since I am creating this date picker through code and adding it to the textfields keyboard, is there more I have to do to change the colour scheme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I've figured out how to set the colours, You cannot use the `.backgroundColor` or `.tintColor` properties in this case. Instead you have to set the value for key (which is the same as the environmental variables!

```
[datePicker setValue:kTextColor4 forKey:@"textColor"];
```

A̶n̶d̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶s̶e̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶b̶a̶c̶k̶g̶r̶o̶u̶n̶d̶ ̶c̶o̶l̶o̶u̶r̶ ̶(̶a̶f̶t̶e̶r̶ ̶m̶u̶c̶h̶ ̶f̶r̶u̶s̶t̶r̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶)̶ ̶I̶ ̶f̶o̶u̶n̶d̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶c̶a̶n̶ ̶s̶e̶t̶ ̶a̶ ̶b̶a̶c̶k̶g̶r̶o̶u̶n̶d̶ ̶c̶o̶l̶o̶u̶r̶ ̶o̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶d̶a̶t̶e̶ ̶p̶i̶c̶k̶e̶r̶'̶s̶ ̶l̶a̶y̶e̶r̶ ̶(̶d̶u̶h̶)̶,̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶_̶`d̶a̶t̶e̶P̶i̶c̶k̶e̶r̶.̶l̶a̶y̶e̶r̶.̶b̶a̶c̶k̶g̶r̶o̶u̶n̶d̶C̶o̶l̶o̶r̶ ̶=̶ ̶k̶B̶a̶c̶k̶g̶r̶o̶u̶n̶d̶C̶o̶l̶o̶r̶1̶.̶C̶G̶C̶o̶l̶o̶r̶;̶` ̶ ̶N̶o̶w̶ ̶m̶y̶ ̶d̶a̶t̶e̶p̶i̶c̶k̶e̶r̶ ̶p̶o̶p̶u̶p̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶s̶t̶y̶l̶e̶d̶ ̶c̶o̶r̶r̶e̶c̶t̶l̶y̶!̶

the solution above did set a background colour but not the right colour (it had a whiteish tint) and I could not for the life of me find the layer responsible. What I found is that I had my textfield configured wrong (style set to dark instead of default) as to set the background colour you MUST set the keyboard to default.

```
_datePicker.backgroundColor = kBackgroundColor1;
```

[image]

And then your date picker will look nice and fancy like so:
[image]